# Understanding useEffect() behaviour and extra re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was doing some tests with the following dummy component, where upon the execution (in the console) I am getting the following result:

```
Rendering:  0
Triggered:  0
Rendering:  4
Triggered:  4
Rendering:  4
```

I struggle to understand why.

First rendering:

- sets `index` to `0`.
- runs useEffect as `undefined` is not `0`
- useEffect requests setting `index` to `4`

Second render:

- `index` is `4`
- why useEffect body is executed again?

Third render:

- why there is re-rendering?

What I would expect is:

```
Rendering:  0
Triggered:  0
Rendering:  4
```

Am I skipping something very obvious?
Could you please help me understand how this works under the hood?

```js
const Example = React.memo(() => {
    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)
    console.log('Rendering: ', index)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Triggered: ', index)
        setIndex(4)
    }, [index])

    return <h1>{index}</h1>
})

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _"runs useEffect as undefined is not 0"_ - useEffect is not executed because of the initial value of `index`; by default, useEffect is executed _after_ the initial render. _"why useEffect body is executed again?"_ - because useEffect depends on `index` and you changed the state from inside of the useEffect, setting `index` to 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of rerenders are actually correct. Let's analyze what happens:

---

1. **Rendering 0** - this is on mount first render (in this state, every `useEffect` is run automatically)

---

2. **Triggered 0** - this is initial triggering of `useEffect`

---

3. **Rendering 4** - this rerender is because you set new state of `index` to `4`

---

4. **Triggered 4** - this is triggered because you changed `index` from 0 to 4

---

5. **Rendering 4** - this is run because state is changed from `4` to `4` (even the value is the same, it will trigger component rerender because React does not know if you set same state, and it needs to run again). In this rerender [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is not run because `index` is 4 again.

---

##### Rationale

If anything changes in a component at any point like `useState` `useContext`, `customHook`, that component will need to rerender.
This also happens if the parent component rerenders, child component will rerender even if your component did not have any changes.

##### Additional rerendering tips and info

To prevent parent unnecessary rerendering of child components from happening you can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), this will rerender your component if props change, but wont prevent your component from rerendering if state or any of the above hooks change in there.

If this seems redundant, it sounds like it, but it is necessary so that react is sure it has the latest state. Running JS like this is faster than having some state memory that checks changes and also it is more transparent for the developer (and just how the [VDOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html#:%7E:text=The%20virtual%20DOM%20(VDOM)%20is,a%20library%20such%20as%20ReactDOM.&text=Since%20%E2%80%9Cvirtual%20DOM%E2%80%9D%20is%20more,it%20to%20mean%20different%20things.) is created)

Comment: Thank you. I've modified the component adding React.memo() wrapper, however it didn't prevent the last rendering from happening. Could you please help me understand why?

Comment: React memo will not prevent that last rerendering as that rerendering is a legit one, Reac.memo is intended to prevent rerendering of child component when parent components get rerendered.

Comment: React.memo does not have anything to do with your situation. I mentioned it as an additional info for rendering

Comment: You won't be able to prevent the last rerender as your code is written now. The thing you can do is remove `[index]` as dependency from that `useEffect` so that it is not run after your `index` is set to 4. In this case you will remove `Triggered 4` and `Rendering 4`. Because you wont enter that `useEffect` where `index` is changed from `4` to "again" `4`. I think that your use case is not a realistic case at all, since you are setting your state and relying on that state to run `useEffect`

Answer (score 2):

Expected output can't be achieved.

useEffect renders on when component mount and on every re-render when state changes(index).

```
const Example = () => {
    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)
    console.log('Rendering: ', index)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Triggered: ', index)
        setIndex(4)
    }, [index])

    return <h1>{index}</h1>
}
```

Output:

- **Rendering: 0** => When component mount first time, that time index is 0
- **Triggered: 0** => On mount useEffect triggers, and state updated(0 to 4)
- **Rendering: 4** => Componet re-rendered because state has changed from (0 to 4)
- **Triggered: 4** => useEffect re-triggered because state has changed(0 to 4)
- **Rendering: 4** => Componet re-rendered because to check whether state has changed or not (4 to 4, **kind of confirmation nothing changed** )

Answer (score 1):

The way useEffect work is it only runs after page component is rendered.

Hope this will help you to understand.

1st render index is 0.

```
Rendering:  0
```

It triggers the useEffect.

```
Triggered:  0
```

Index is updated in the useEffect but not in the component.
Then render updates the index to 4.

```
Rendering:  4
```

The useEffect runs because index has changed.

```
Triggered:  4
```

The component is rendered again but index is still 4 so the useEffect wont run again.

```
Rendering:  4
```